# Reproduction figure with Pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need your help, I have to reproduce this figure to explain **Peak Over Threshold method** (POT) [image] using Pgfplot.
Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Have you tried anything yourself? If so, always nice if you share that. (For example, a `ycomb` plot will get you a long way.)

Comment: Just follow @TorbjørnT.'s suggestion and plot twice, once thick and one thin, and clip the plots in upper or lower half.

Comment: How to do that??

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example. The code contains several comments, but please ask if anything is unclear.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % also loads pgfplots

% make a table containing y-values and labels for (some of) the data points
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
y,label
8,$Y_{1}$
2,
5.6,$Y_{2}$
5,$Y_{3}$
6,
4,
9,$Y_{j}$
10,
4,
}\mydata

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  % 
  axis lines=middle,
  % labels for axes
  ylabel={$X_i$},
  xlabel={$i$},
  % set axes limits
  ymin=0,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=9.9,
  % define where to place ticks on the axes
  % and what text labels to use for the ticks
  ytick={4.5},
  yticklabels={$u$},
  xtick={1,2,3,9},
  xticklabels={$1$,$2$,$3$,$n$},
  tickwidth=0pt,
  % turn on grid lines for ticks on the y-axis
  ymajorgrids,
  % set the style of the single grid line
  grid style={densely dotted, gray}
]

\addplot [
   % comb plots are lines from the axis to the point
   ycomb,
   thick,
   % nodes near coords is for adding automatic labels at data points
   nodes near coords,
   % set the style of those nodes
   nodes near coords style={font=\small},
   % the following states that the text used for the labels should
   % be given explicitly in the data stream
   % symbolic means that it should not be parsed as a number
   point meta=explicit symbolic
 ]
 table[
    % define the x-coordinate
    x expr=\coordindex+1,
    % get y-values from the column named y in the table
    y=y,
    % get the data for the point labels from the column named label
    meta=label
  ] {\mydata};

\addplot [
   ycomb,
   thick,
   gray
 ]
 table[
    x expr=\coordindex+1,
    % the y-coordinate is defined  by the given calculation, i.e.
    % the smallest value of the y-value from the table and 4.5
    y expr={min(\thisrow{y}, 4.5)}
  ] {\mydata};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot for your help, very nice.

Comment: I have this  error when executing script  : Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/nodes near coords style',isspelled it. t

Comment: @LAIDIMohamed Do you get that from the exact code in my answer?

Comment: Yes using your answer. I don't know what 's the problem?

Comment: @LAIDIMohamed I have no idea why either, if you copied the code in my answer into an empty file and compiled it, you should not get that error. If you made any modifications, you need to tell me what you did.

Comment: I have copied the code of your answer into an empty file and compiled it, I haven't made changes to it.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `.log` file? Put it on Pastebin or similar.

Comment: The problem was the line : "nodes near coords style={font=\small},"

Comment: @LAIDIMohamed I'm so sorry, you actually said that in your first comment about the error, I just completely misread it. Anyway, what it does is just to set the style of those label nodes, you can try the equivalent `every node near coord/.append style={font=\small}` if you need to. Perhaps you have an older version of `pgfplots`, where the shorthand `nodes near coords style` wasn't yet defined.